# disable clipboard option Edittext

Tags: android

I am struggling with removing PASTE option. Although i am able to remove PASTE option from menu while selecting text from edtittext but in some devices instead of Paste, Clipboard option is visible. Can anyone suggest any workaround ?

```
 @Override
    public int getSelectionStart() {
        for (StackTraceElement element : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
             Log.e("TAG","====="+ element.getMethodName()+ "====");
            if (element.getMethodName().equals("canPaste") || element.equals("canSuggest")) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return super.getSelectionStart();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all types of copy paste from EditText by using this kotlin extension function:

```
fun EditText.disableCopyPaste() {
    this.customInsertionActionModeCallback= object : ActionMode.Callback{
        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
        }

    }

    this.customSelectionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback{
        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
        }

    }

    this.isLongClickable = false
    this.setTextIsSelectable(false)
    this.addTextChangedListener( object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            if (after - count > 1) {
                this@disableCopyPaste.setText(s)
                this@disableCopyPaste.setSelection(s.toString().length)
            }
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }

    })
}
```

Link reference: https://gist.github.com/SanikaVanjari/83758a53c9d52012e034e855c4f8653e